# How to execute a JavaScript function when its name is passed as a string in function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, hide, show

how can I use function name passed as argument.

example:

```
showError('container', 'id', '- message', 'show');
showError('container', 'id', '', 'hide');


function showError(container, id, msg, action)
{    
    if(action == 'show') {  
        $('#' + container).show();       
        $('#' + id).html(msg).show();
    }
    else {  
        $('#' + container).hide();       
        $('#' + id).html(msg).hide();
    }

}
```

Comment: try eval() http://stackoverflow.com/questions/86513/why-is-using-the-javascript-eval-function-a-bad-idea

Comment: @LosManos: -1. [Read](http://stackoverflow.com/a/87260/1048572) before you link, and then don't do it.

Comment: @Bergi: yes?  I tried to say that eval was an option but without having to write text that explained the pros and cons of it.  The other answers are way better though - hence only a comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the *general* case, the bracket notation is good.  In your case, use `toggle`:

```
function showError(container, id, msg, action)
{    
        $('#' + container).toggle(action === 'show');       
        $('#' + id).html(msg).toggle(action === 'show');
}
```

or even (as Bergi suggests):

```
function showError(container, id, msg)
{    
        $('#' + container).toggle(!!msg);       
        $('#' + id).html(msg);
}
```

(It uses my own invention, the double-bang `!!`, which converts truthy or falsy values to their Boolean equivalents.)

Answer (score 3):

`obj.foo()` really is a 2 step thing.  `obj.foo` returns a function object, and then the `()` executes it.  `obj['foo']` returns the same function object, so add a `()` to execute it.

Since `obj['foo']` is the same as `obj.foo`.  Even if the value on that property is a function.  So you can always access any property with the `[]` accessor, using a string as the key name.

```
$('#' + container)[action]();
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Member_Operators#Bracket_notation) to access the respective method by a string:

```
function showError(container, id, msg, action) {    
    $('#' + container)[action]();       
    $('#' + id).html(msg)[action]();
}
```

However, your method looks strange. I'd recommend to limit the action to the two values, and do that automatically:

```
function showError(container, id, msg) {
    var action = msg=='' ? 'hide' : 'show';
    $('#' + container)[action]();       
    $('#' + id).text(msg)[action]();
}
```